# Problem with sending variable to another function

Tags: python

1. Call function what checking file content, size, etc
2. Call function if file was changed by file size, if file size changed check file content, add changes to list or delete from list
   Question how to use variable in other function correctly?

```
import re
import os
from time import sleep

hosts_file = "hosts.txt"

class Hosts(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hosts_file = hosts_file

    def get_file_size(self):
        f_size = os.stat(self.hosts_file)
        return f_size.st_size

def work_with_hosts_file():
    host_file_work = Hosts()
    file_size = host_file_work.get_file_size()
    return file_size # use this var

def compare_hosts_file_size(): # in this function
    host_file_work = Hosts()
    file_size_check = host_file_work.get_file_size()
    if file_size != file_size_check:
        #do stuff        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    work_with_hosts_file()
    get_connection_hosts_info()
    while True:
        compare_hosts_file_size()
        sleep(5.0)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what’s the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the returned value of `work_with_hosts_file()` to a variable, and then pass that as an argument to `compare_hosts_file_size()`.

```
import re
import os
from time import sleep

hosts_file = "hosts.txt"

class Hosts(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hosts_file = hosts_file

    def get_file_size(self):
        f_size = os.stat(self.hosts_file)
        return f_size.st_size

def work_with_hosts_file():
    host_file_work = Hosts()
    file_size = host_file_work.get_file_size()
    return file_size # use this var

def compare_hosts_file_size(file_size): # in this function
    host_file_work = Hosts()
    file_size_check = host_file_work.get_file_size()
    if file_size != file_size_check:
        #do stuff        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = work_with_hosts_file()
    get_connection_hosts_info()
    while True:
        compare_hosts_file_size(size)
        sleep(5.0)
```